# Why rewrite directive causes "301 Moved Permanently" with Nginx?

Tags: webserver, nginx, redirect

Below is a much simplified version of what I have in the configuration file of a server run by Nginx 1.2.5, yet it causes `301 Moved Permanently` with `Location: http://example.com/phpmyadmin/` before serving data, which is not what I expected from the default behavior of the `rewrite` directive.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /pma {
        rewrite ^ /phpmyadmin;
    }
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /var/www;
        index Documentation.html;
    }
}
```

(Again, the example is highly simplified and altered, the config makes perfect sense in its original form.)

When I go to `http://example.com/pma` in a browser, the data is served but the URL in the address bar changes to `http://example.com/phpmyadmin/` while it was supposed to stay `http://example.com/pma`.

How do I avoid Nginx sending `301 Moved Permanently` so that it doesn't expose the actual directory structure on my server?